# How to change the vaadin-icon stroke-width using a CSS file?

Tags: css, svg, vaadin

I want to change the `vaadin-icon` `stroke-width` using the `CSS` file but my changes in the CSS file don't have any effect on the icon.
I want to do this for just one icon in one place in my application, not for the whole application. I am using Vaadin 23 with Lit-element.

Any idea why and any solution is welcome.

```
${mobile ? html`
           <span class="closing-icon">
                <vaadin-icon class="close-big" @click=${(e) => this.$server.close()} icon="vaadin:close" > </vaadin-icon>
           </span>`
        : ''}
```

**CSS file**

```
span vaadin-icon svg g path{
    stroke-width:0.1; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The svg elements are inside the shadow DOM of the `<vaadin-icon>` component. You need to inject the styles inside the shadow DOM for the to apply.

If you’re building a Vaadin Flow or Hilla app, you can do that with a custom theme, and a component-specific stylesheet.

`frontend/themes/mytheme/components/vaadin-icon.css`:

```css
path {
 stroke-width: 0.1; 
}
```

If not, you can use the `registerStyles` function from the ThemableMixin package:

```js
import {registerStyles, css} from '@vaadin/themable-mixin';

registerStyles('vaadin-icon', css`
  path {
   stroke-width: 0.1; 
  }
`);
```